# Post-apocalyptic novel: an astronaut returns to an Earth reverted to the stone age

Tags: story-identification, space, post-apocalyptic

I read this scifi post apocalyptic book back in mid 90s.  It revolved around an astronaut who had been in deep space, and upon returning to Earth, he found that civilization had returned almost to a Stone Age type time period.  Barbaric cave people living in tribes.   It was a great read and thought I still owned it, but can't find it and I have exhausted Google.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185808/identify-a-title-and-author-for-a-certain-post-apocalyptic-series-set-in-the-us

Comment: Are you sure it was a full length novel? Could it be a short story or novella? Was the astronaut part of a crew or by themselves?

Answer (score 5):

I read a series of books like that once by [Paul O Williams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_O._Williams), but I didn't read the first 2 so I don't know if it had the space travel element. The series is called the [*Pelbar Cycle*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?930).

*The Breaking of Northwall* (1981)
*The Ends of the Circle* (1981)
*The Dome in the Forest* (1981)
*The Fall of the Shell* (1982)
*An Ambush of Shadows* (1983)
*Song of the Axe* (1984)
*The Sword of Forbearance* (1985)

Answer (score 5):

I was also looking for this great book and just found it and your post during my search. If you have not found it, *[The Return](http://theporporbooksblog.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/book-review-return-by-richard-maynard-4.html)* by Richard Maynard.

[image: Book Cover]

> ‘The Return’ starts with a voyage into interstellar space by a team of seven British astronauts. Their goal is to travel faster-than-light to the Alpha Centauri system and back, a journey which should take the equivalent of sixteen years of Earth-time. Unfortunately the ship encounters navigational problems and goes off-course; by the time the crew corrects the error, they have been traveling for 15 years ship-time. The crew must confront the awful fact that perhaps as many as 60 years...or as many as 400 years.... have passed on Earth since their departure.

....

> And the humans that populate these landscapes are semi-literate savages wrapped in animal furs and toting spears. And they are not friendly, as the starship crew soon discovers….

Comment: The book has also been proffered as answer at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85374/23243