# Christian novel about astronauts returning from Mars to a depopulated Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel, mars, christian

This was a novel I read around 2011 in spurts while visiting my girlfriend who worked in a bookstore. It was in the "Christian novel" section and had the following plot:

Astronauts return from their trip to Mars and Houston is enveloped by a <s>hurricane</s> bright light, cutting off radio communications. When they finally exit their ship after landing, they're the only people around and walk around empty suburbs.

I'm fairly certain the captain/protagonist was a woman, and she routinely had flashbacks to falling into some sort of tunnel while on Mars.

Note, this definitely **isn't** *The Return* as seen in this answer: [Novel about astronauts returning to depopulated Earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51466/novel-about-astronauts-returning-to-depopulated-earth)

Comment: Is the Rapture explanation the surprise ending?  If so, is there any way to ask this question (and display its answer) without spoiling?

Comment: To be honest, I never finished the book, which I why I was wanting to look it up again. Given that it was in the Christian lit section I assumed it wasn't a twist, but once I read it, I can update the title accordingly

Comment: I saw a book in a bookstore once that had some astronauts finding a mysterious artifact on another planet, and it turned out to be Noah's Ark or something. The fact that it was in the Christian Lit section basically was a spoiler.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson I finished the book, turns out I made wrong assumptions about the biblical nature of the book, so I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Might this be [*Offworld*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1027074) (2009) by Robin Parrish?  The blurb reads:

> The return of NASA's first manned mission to Mars was supposed to be a momentous day. But when the crew loses touch with ground control before entry, things look bleak. Safe after a treacherous landing, the crew emerges to discover the unthinkable--every man, woman, child, and animal has vanished without a trace. Alone now on their home planet, the crew sets out to discover where everyone has gone--and how to get them back--only to discover they may not be as alone as they thought.

The [Goodreads page](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5841844-offworld) has a number of reviews that give some more details:

- There are 4 astronauts, including 1 woman
- The crew encounter some kind of anomaly on their return to Earth
- It is a "Christian Science Fiction" book

(Note: I found this using the search `site:goodreads.com/book mars astronauts rapture` where it appeared near the top of the first page.)

Comment: Yes! This is definitely it, I knew from the first sentence of the blurb, those words were super familiar! I know why I gravitated too the book now too, since the author and I share a first name.

Comment: maybe the book explains more, but i find it kind of curious that every person on earth is worthy of being raptured, and apparently the only unforgiveable sin is the act of going to mars :)

Comment: @JustinL. Extraterrestrial travel was an unexpected bug in the system that the "gather up all the people" code didn't account for?

Comment: ah, my point was that the rapture is typically supposed to distinguish the "saved" from the un-saved/sinful.  in typical stories, only a fraction is saved and the rest are left behind to deal with their sins. but in this story apparently every person on earth is "saved", the only way to not be saved (and sinful enough to not be raptured) is by going to mars.

Comment: @Randal'Thor:  Edge cases are the worst

Comment: @MichaelSeifert. You have a good point. This should have been filed under "Computer Science Fiction"

Comment: @JustinL. The book never mentions rapture at all, not even any supernatural entity involved. It seems people just use rapture for "everyone disappearing", which makes it more confusing when talking about a book specifically in this genre.